# Merge data(Multiple Records) from 2 tables based on a condition

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables with the below Structure.

Table - 1

```
Cust_ID
Order_Date
Order_time
Cust_Name
Cust_Address
Order_Status
Emp_ID
Cust_Prod_Cost
Cust_Balance
```

Table - 2

```
Cust_ID
Delivered_Time
Delivered_Qty
Payment_Type
Cust_Prod_Cost
Cust_Balance
Amount_Paid
Order_Status
Emp_ID
WHID
```

Table - 3

```
Cust_ID
Order_Date
Order_time
Delivery_Time
Cust_Prod_Cost
Delivered_Qty
Payment_Type
Amt_To_Pay
Amount_Paid
Due_Amount
Order_Status
Emp_ID
WHID
```

Now i would like to merge the data from Table - 1 and 2 into Table -3 when Table2-Cust_ID=Table1.Cust_ID and Table2.Order_Status='0'.

Can you please help me out with an SQL Server Query??. I tried many possible ways, but with no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Insert Into Table3
(
    Cust_ID
    Order_Date
    Order_time
    Delivery_Time
    Cust_Prod_Cost
    Delivered_Qty
    Payment_Type
    Amt_To_Pay
    Amount_Paid
    Due_Amount
    Order_Status
    Emp_ID
    WHID
)
Select t1.Cust_Id,
       t1.Order_Date,
       t1.Order_Time,
       t2.Delivered_Time,
       t2.Cust_Prod_Cost,
       t2.Delivered_Qty,
       t2.Payment_Type,
       Amt_To_Pay (doesn't exist in t1 or t2),
       t2.Amount_Paid,
       Due_Amount (doesn't exist in t1 or t2),
       t1.Order_Status,
       t1.Emp_ID,
       t1.WHID
From Table1 t1
Inner Join Table2 t2 On t2.Cust_Id = t1.Cust_Id
    And t2.Order_Status = '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
A.Cust_ID,Order_Date,Order_time,Delivery_Time,Cust_Prod_Cost,
Delivered_Qty,Payment_Type,Amt_To_Pay,Amount_Paid,
Due_Amount,Order_Status,A.Emp_ID,WHID
FROM TABLE1 A 
JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.Cust_ID=B.Cust_ID AND B.Order_Status=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following sql:

```
    INSERT INTO Table3 (
                        Cust_ID
                        ,Order_Date
                        ,Order_time
                        ,Delivery_Time
                        ,Cust_Prod_Cost
                        ,Delivered_Qty, Payment_Type
                        ,Amt_To_Pay, Amount_Paid
                        ,Due_Amount
                        ,Order_Status
                        ,Emp_ID
                        ,WHID
    )
    SELECT t1.Cust_ID
           ,t1.Order_Date
           ,t1.Order_time
           ,t2.Delivered_Time
           ,t2.Cust_Prod_Cost
          ,t2.Delivered_Qty
          ,t2.Payment_Type
          ,NULL AS Amount_To_Pay
          ,t2.Amount_Paid
          ,NULL AS Due_Amount
          ,t2.Due_Amount
          ,t2.WHID  
    FORM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.Cust_ID = t2.Cust_ID 
    WHERE t2.Order_Status = 0
```

Replace the `NULL` with valid values